# How to use a os.DirEntry object with pandas read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system

So I'd like to create a new dataframe from different csv files, my code looks the following:

```
root = "/some/dir"
for folder in os.scandir(root):
        newDF = pd.DataFrame()
        for data in os.scandir(path):
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(data.name, "a_filename*"):
                temp = pd.read_csv(data, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")  # error
                newDF[list(temp)[1]] = temp[list(temp)[1]]
```

But when I try to read the CSV file I get the following error:

```py
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'posix.DirEntry'>
```

I just can't wrap my head around how to use the DirEntry instance returned by `os.scandir()`. I also tried to pass `data.name` and `os.fsdecode(data)`, but without luck.

What is the right thing to pass to `pd.read_csv()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) objects define a [**`path`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.path) attribute you can query which returns the path (may or may not be fully qualified) to that file.

> **`path`**
>   The entry’s full path name: equivalent to `os.path.join(scandir_path,
>   entry.name)` where `scandir_path` is the `scandir()` path argument.

In your case, you'd simply have to do

```
df = pd.read_csv(data.path, encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```